# Trying to get my JavaScript to work out the 2 numbers entered to get calculated by pc.

Tags: javascript

Just wondering if anyone can work out why I keep getting for eg. 3+3=33 and not 6.

The rest of the coding works fine for the divide and times its the addition that keeps stuffing up and wont come up with the correct answer.. please help if you can.

1. here is my code:

   ```
   <html>
    <head>
     <title>Practical Task 8 </title>
    </head>

       <body>

        <button onclick="myFunction()">Press & Enter First Digit & Second Digit</button>


        <script type="TEXT/JavaScript">

         function myFunction()
               {

           var x=prompt("Please enter first number","0");
           var y=prompt("Please enter second number","0");

               var sum = x;
               var sum2 = y;
               var n = (x * y);
               var n2 = (x / y);
               var n3 = (x + y);

          document.write(sum + " + " + sum2 + " = " + n3);

          document.write("<BR>" + sum + " * " + sum2 + " = " + n);

          document.write("<BR>" + sum + " / " + sum2 + " = " + n2);

              }




           </script>



       </body>


   </html>
   ```

Comment: You need to convert them to int. You can do `Number(x)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're performing string concatenation, not integer addition.

Use `parseInt` first:

```
x = parseInt( x, 10 );
y = parseInt( y, 10 );
```

[MDN recommends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) always specifying the radix (the `10` part) to avoid problems, such as if a user prepends a number with `0` (where it'll be parsed as octal), or if different browsers have a different default radix (wtf, I know!).

You have to do this because the output of `prompt` is always a `string`, even if it's a number (e.g. `"10"` or `"0123"`), you need to tell JavaScript to interpret the data as a number (use `parseInt` if it's an integer (a whole number), or use `parseFloat` if you'll accept numbers with decimal places). Confusingly the `+` operator works for both `string` and `number` types, where it performs either concatenation (i.e. joining strings together like glue) or addition depending on the type of its operands.

Comment: Don't forget to add the base 10 radix.

Comment: so instead of the line 'var sum = x;' and line 'var sum2 = y;' put in your lines? x = parseInt( x ); and y = parseInt( y );

Comment: @Dai umm question where do I add the line of coding.. or do I remove var sum = x; and change it to x = parseInt( x, 10 );

Comment: Thank you Dai Much appreciated.. I changed the var sum = x; and y one over to the x = parseInt( x, 10); and same for y.. THANKYOU MATE YOUR A LEGEND!!

Comment: Clifford - I suggest you use _parseFloat()_ as suggested towards the end of this answer, or _Number()_ as suggested in a comment above. Or give the user an error message if they don't enter integers. But don't just ignore any decimal places that might be entered, as will happen with _parseInt()._

Answer (score 2):

Because your code is adding strings.

User input is always string.

You need to `parseInt(x, 10)` and `parseInt(y, 10)` to parse the string value into int base 10.

Comment: but the coding is working on the times and divide question and answers.. and the + one isn't working hang on il try your one first juno

Comment: Why _parseInt()_? The user is going to be confused if they enter 1.9 and 2.9 and get an answer of 3 because your code threw away the decimal places. Convert to numbers, not integers. Clifford -   your inputs are strings, but the multiplication and division operators automatically convert (or attempt to convert) their operands to numbers, so those operations work. The + operator is different, it does string concatenation or mathematical addition depending on the types of the operands.

Comment: But it all depends on what the OP is trying to get from user input. For me, I would use either parseInt or parseFloat to make the intention clear.